# GUI become's small whenever I make it visible

Tags: java, swing

I've been making an app with java swing and JavaFX and didn't run into a problem until now. Whenever I set the guis visibility to true, the GUI becomes very small, when it should be 1150 px wide, 900 px tall. Does anyone get any ideas?

Main Gui code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class mainGui extends JFrame{

    public static JFrame mainScreen = new JFrame("Tamo");

    public mainGui() {

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();

        mainScreen.setSize(1150, 900);
        mainScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainScreen.setResizable(false);
        mainScreen.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        topPanel.setBackground(new Color(226, 230, 204));
        topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1150, 100));

        mainScreen.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\uname\\Desktop\\TamoDienynas\\pngs\\tamo.png");
        mainScreen.setIconImage(icon.getImage());

        mainScreen.setVisible(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new mainGui();
    }
}
```

Class which make's the gui visible:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import static me.rockorbonk.tamodienynas.GUI.mainGui.mainScreen;

public class loginGui extends JFrame  implements ActionListener {


    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JLabel userLabel;
    private static JLabel passwordLabel;
    private static JLabel success;
    private static JButton login;
    private static JTextField userText;
    private static JPasswordField passwordText;

    loginGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(350, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);

        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(userText);

        passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        passwordText = new JPasswordField();
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        login = new JButton("Login");
        login.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        login.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(login);

        success = new JLabel("");
        success.setBounds(10, 110, 300, 25);
        panel.add(success);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\uname\\Desktop\\TamoDienynas\\pngs\\tamo.png");
        frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String uname = userText.getText();
        String pwd = passwordText.getText();

        if(uname.equals("rokasbruz") && pwd.equals("Rokas123")) {
            success.setText("Sekmingai prisijungėte!");

            ActionListener l = evt -> {
                userLabel.setVisible(false);
                passwordLabel.setVisible(false);
                userText.setVisible(false);
                passwordText.setVisible(false);
                login.setVisible(false);

                success.setVisible(false);
                frame.setVisible(false);
                mainScreen.setVisible(true);
                mainScreen.pack();
            };
            Timer timer = new Timer(2000, l);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }
        else{
            success.setText("Slapyvardis arba slaptažodis nesutampa!");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new loginGui();

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. I'm using IntelliJ ultimate as the IDE

-Rock

Comment: There are so many problems with this GUI it should probably be put to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) first.

Comment: PS: I tried compiling the code and saw two errors. For better help sooner on run-time problems, [edit] to add a [mre] that compiles without ***any*** changes.

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was that I needed to use the class constructor and not use the mainScreen frame

Comment: You should NOT be using static variables. You should NOT be extending Jframe. You should NOT be using a null layout or setBounds(). Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Start with examples from the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) to learn Swing basics.

Answer (score 0):

`mainScreen` is just a `JFrame` that does not contain anything. Hence when you make it visible, all you see is the title bar. In order to initialize `mainScreen` you need to call `mainGui` constructor. Nonetheless, as Andrew Thompson wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197136/gui-becomes-small-whenever-i-make-it-visible#comment125850926_71197136), your style of coding a *Swing* application is very unusual. Consider using a [dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) as your login window.

Here is your code that displays `mainScreen` as I believe you intended. I only changed the `ActionListener`, in class `loginGui`, that displays `mainGui`. I added one line which is indicated with the comment *ADDED THIS LINE*

```java
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import static me.rockorbonk.tamodienynas.GUI.mainGui.mainScreen;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class loginGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JLabel userLabel;
    private static JLabel passwordLabel;
    private static JLabel success;
    private static JButton login;
    private static JTextField userText;
    private static JPasswordField passwordText;

    loginGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(350, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);

        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(userText);

        passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        passwordText = new JPasswordField();
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        login = new JButton("Login");
        login.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        login.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(login);

        success = new JLabel("");
        success.setBounds(10, 110, 300, 25);
        panel.add(success);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\uname\\Desktop\\TamoDienynas\\pngs\\tamo.png");
        frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String uname = userText.getText();
        String pwd = passwordText.getText();

        if (uname.equals("rokasbruz") && pwd.equals("Rokas123")) {
            success.setText("Sekmingai prisijungėte!");

            ActionListener l = evt -> {
                userLabel.setVisible(false);
                passwordLabel.setVisible(false);
                userText.setVisible(false);
                passwordText.setVisible(false);
                login.setVisible(false);

                success.setVisible(false);
                frame.setVisible(false);
                new mainGui(); // ADDED THIS LINE
                mainScreen.setVisible(true);
                mainScreen.pack();
            };
            Timer timer = new Timer(2000, l);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }
        else {
            success.setText("Slapyvardis arba slaptažodis nesutampa!");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new loginGui();
    }
}
```

Here is how it appears (after logging in).

[image: screen capture]